# Android : java.lang.OutOfMemoryError:

Tags: java, android, xml, animation, android-imageview

I developed an application that uses lots of images on Android.

There are lots of images present in drawable folder say more then 100, I am developing application for animation of images. I used imageview to show GIF images. I have used the concept of Split gif images into multiple PNG format images and then use it.

Each time the user enters to the app, I can see the memory growing more and more until user gets the `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`.

So what is the best/correct way to handle many images?

Below is my code:

dog_animation.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/DogView"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/dog_animation"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.19" />
```

dog_animation.xml (Drawable folder)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/image"
    android:duration="50"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/image1"
    android:duration="50"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/image2"
    android:duration="50"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/image3"
    android:duration="50"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/image4"
    android:duration="50"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/image5"
    android:duration="50"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/image6"
    android:duration="50"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/image7"
    android:duration="50"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/image8"
    android:duration="50"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/image9"
    android:duration="50"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/image10"
    android:duration="50"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/image11"
    android:duration="50"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/image12"
    android:duration="50"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/image13"
    android:duration="50"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/image14"
    android:duration="50"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/image15"
    android:duration="50"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/image16"
    android:duration="50"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/image17"
    android:duration="50"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/image18"
    android:duration="50"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/image19"
    android:duration="50"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/image20"
    android:duration="50"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/image21"
    android:duration="50"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/image22"
    android:duration="50"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/image23"
    android:duration="50"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/image24"
    android:duration="50"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/image25"
    android:duration="50"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/image26"
    android:duration="50"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/image27"
    android:duration="50"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/image28"
    android:duration="50"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/image29"
    android:duration="50"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/image30"
    android:duration="50"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/image31"
    android:duration="50"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/image32"
    android:duration="50"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/image33"
    android:duration="50"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/image34"
    android:duration="50"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/image35"
    android:duration="50"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/image36"
    android:duration="50"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/image37"
    android:duration="50"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/image38"
    android:duration="50"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/image39"
    android:duration="50"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/image40"
    android:duration="50"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/image41"
    android:duration="50"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/image42"
    android:duration="50"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/image43"
    android:duration="50"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/image44"
    android:duration="50"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/image45"
    android:duration="50"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/image46"
    android:duration="50"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/image47"
    android:duration="50"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/image48"
    android:duration="50"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/image49"
    android:duration="50"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/image50"
    android:duration="50"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/image51"
    android:duration="50"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/image52"
    android:duration="50"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/image53"
    android:duration="50"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/image54"
    android:duration="50"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/image55"
    android:duration="50"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/image56"
    android:duration="50"/>
```

Dog_Animation.java

```
public class Dog_Animation extends Activity {

Timer timer = new Timer();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.dog_animation);

    ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.dog_animation);
    img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dog_animation);
    AnimationDrawable frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) img
            .getBackground();
    frameAnimation.start();

    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Dog_Animation.this,
                    Man_Animation.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }, 10000);
}
}
```

Now the problem is when i try to move from one activity to another which has same some other image to animate it's giving me error of `java.lang.OutOfMemory`.

I have tried with so many different solution like

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    unbindDrawables(findViewById(R.id.DogView));
    System.gc();
}

private void unbindDrawables(View view) {
    if (view.getBackground() != null) {
        view.getBackground().setCallback(null);
    }
    if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
        for (int i = 0; i < ((ViewGroup) view).getChildCount(); i++) {
            unbindDrawables(((ViewGroup) view).getChildAt(i));
        }
        ((ViewGroup) view).removeAllViews();
    }
}
```

and so other also but any solution is not working for me. Please help me to solve this issue.  even i have referred http://androidactivity.wordpress.com/2011/09/24/solution-for-outofmemoryerror-bitmap-size-exceeds-vm-budget/ this link but not getting solve the issue.

Comment: The best way is to search here or on Google.  There are MANY answers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Strange out of memory issue while loading an image to a Bitmap object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/strange-out-of-memory-issue-while-loading-an-image-to-a-bitmap-object)

Comment: Hey Simon, I have tried and searched a lot in google but not getting proper solution. That is the only reason i have asked this question/

Comment: Looks like You have memory leak in the app. Have You tried to follow the tutorial here: http://android-developers.blogspot.kr/2011/03/memory-analysis-for-android.html (also, there's corresponding Google I/O talk available)?

Comment: Hey sandrstar, I have not tried the solution given by you, but surly i will try and let you know weather it is working or not in my case. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Don't call System.gc(); manually it's a bad practice, if you want a complete answer why refer to this link: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2414120/2958420

Comment: Did you figure it out? I have the same problem...but I'm only using four images in my drawable...And I only have one activity. What does `android:largeHeap="true"` do? Thanks

Answer (score 20):

In your AndroidManifest.xml keep this inside application tag, add largeHeap like this:

```
<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:largeHeap="true"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

try stopping your animation at onPause(). there is a big chance its not getting GCED because of that. 
also optimize ur bitmaps using this site http://tinypng.org, if you don't need the alpha layer, set it to 24bit

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dog_animation);
```

By:

```
img.setImageBitmap(decodeSampleBitmapFromResource(R.drawable.dog_animation, width, height));
//dont forget to replace width and heigh by your imageview dimension
```

An add:

```
public static int calculateInSampleSize(
            BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        final int heightRatio = Math.round((float) height / (float) reqHeight);
        final int widthRatio = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);

        inSampleSize = heightRatio < widthRatio ? heightRatio : widthRatio;
    }

    return inSampleSize;
}
```

and

```
public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res, int resId,
        int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
}
```

This is from:
http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Answer (score 1):

In the above answer there is a `getResources()` missing in

```
img.setImageBitmap(decodeSampleBitmapFromResource(R.drawable.dog_animation, width, height));
```

so it becomes

```
img.setImageBitmap(decodeSampleBitmapFromResource(getResources(), R.drawable.dog_animation, width, height));
```

Answer (score 0):

Few days ago, I had the same issue and it generated a similar log.
So this is how I went about solving the issue.

I learned that the pixel of an image being loaded in an ImageView in Android Studio mustn't exceed width 1440 and height 2560.

The most voted solution on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32244851/androidjava-lang-outofmemoryerror-failed-to-allocate-a-23970828-byte-allocatio) asked is to add the following in our manifest file: android:hardwareAccelerated="false" , android:largeHeap="true"

[just as show in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRQnk.png)
As I implemented this, the error wasn't thrown, but this did not work for all devices, it rather only worked for my emulator.

So, to solve this dilema for my phone, I simply cropped the associated images to the limit pixel after checking the pixel of each image and discarded that was too large for cropping(resizing).
Note: for a large number of images you can right a code that checks for the images that exceed the amount of pixel required.

this is the link to my issue on github.com ([allenbangai](https://gist.github.com/allenbangai/835e61cbdc0bd97f674f032891d60135))

Answer (score -5):

```
try {
    //Code here that cause OutOfMemoryError
} catch (Error ee) {
    ee.printStacktrace();
}
```