# Error when inflating the ImageButton

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, imagebutton, android-inflate

I click the ImageButton in Fragment-A , And it will change to Fragment-B.

But if I add the two ImageButton in Fragment-B , it will crash.

The following code is in Fragment-A.

```
ImageButton FileButton = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.FileButton) ;

        FileButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                boolean engineerMode = ((MainActivity) getActivity()).mEngineerMode ;
                    Fragment fragment = FileBrowserFragment.newInstance(null, null, null) ;
                    MainActivity.addFragment(MjpegPlayerFragment.this, fragment) ;              
            }
        }) ;
```

The following code is in the XML file of Fragment-A.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#000000" >


                    <Space 
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="4"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/camera_album"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:background="@drawable/camera_album" 
                android:contentDescription="@string/imagebut_cmaera_album"/>

            <Space 
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="8"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/phone_album"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:background="@drawable/phone_album"
                android:contentDescription="@string/imagebut_phone_album"/>

            <Space 
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        </LinearLayout>



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/browserTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:text="@string/label_file_browser"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/browserList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/group_background"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

And the Error Log is

```
D/MJPEG Player(18485): Fragment paused
D/dalvikvm(18485): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2732K, 16% free 50454K/59719K, paused 17ms, total 18ms
I/dalvikvm-heap(18485): Grow heap (frag case) to 62.012MB for 4194320-byte allocation
D/dalvikvm(18485): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1028K, 15% free 54548K/63879K, paused 16ms, total 16ms
I/dalvikvm-heap(18485): Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 4194320-byte allocation
D/dalvikvm(18485): GC_BEFORE_OOM freed 9K, 15% free 54538K/63879K, paused 27ms, total 27ms
E/dalvikvm-heap(18485): Out of memory on a 4194320-byte allocation.
I/dalvikvm(18485): "main" prio=5 tid=1 RUNNABLE
I/dalvikvm(18485):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x416cd6b8 self=0x400da030
I/dalvikvm(18485):   | sysTid=18485 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1075394608
I/dalvikvm(18485):   | schedstat=( 1039401788 552784985 2517 ) utm=54 stm=49 core=0
I/dalvikvm(18485):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
I/dalvikvm(18485):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:500)
I/dalvikvm(18485):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:353)
I/dalvikvm(18485):   at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:785)
I/dalvikvm(18485):   at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1935)
I/dalvikvm(18485):   at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
I/dalvikvm(18485):   at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3392)
I/dalvikvm(18485):   at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:114)
I/dalvikvm(18485):   at android.widget.ImageButton.<init>(ImageButton.java:87)
I/dalvikvm(18485):   at android.widget.ImageButton.<init>(ImageButton.java:83)
I/dalvikvm(18485):   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
I/dalvikvm(18485):   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
I/dalvikvm(18485):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
I/dalvikvm(18485):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
I/dalvikvm(18485):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
I/dalvikvm(18485):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
I/dalvikvm(18485):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
I/dalvikvm(18485):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
I/dalvikvm(18485):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
I/dalvikvm(18485):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
I/dalvikvm(18485):   at tw.com.a_i_t.IPCamViewer.FileBrowser.FileBrowserFragment.onCreateView(FileBrowserFragment.java:200)
I/dalvikvm(18485):   at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:833)
I/dalvikvm(18485):   at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1039)
I/dalvikvm(18485):   at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:635)
I/dalvikvm(18485):   at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1405)
I/dalvikvm(18485):   at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:441)
I/dalvikvm(18485):   at tw.com.a_i_t.IPCamViewer.MainActivity.addFragment(MainActivity.java:131)
I/dalvikvm(18485):   at tw.com.a_i_t.IPCamViewer.Viewer.MjpegPlayerFragment$4.onClick(MjpegPlayerFragment.java:1145)
I/dalvikvm(18485):   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4147)
I/dalvikvm(18485):   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17161)
I/dalvikvm(18485):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
I/dalvikvm(18485):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
I/dalvikvm(18485):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
I/dalvikvm(18485):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4786)
I/dalvikvm(18485):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
I/dalvikvm(18485):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
I/dalvikvm(18485):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
I/dalvikvm(18485):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
I/dalvikvm(18485):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
I/dalvikvm(18485): 
D/skia    (18485): --- bitmap->allocPixels failed
D/AndroidRuntime(18485): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm(18485): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x416cc450)
--------- beginning of /dev/log/system

E/AndroidRuntime(18485): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(18485): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #31: Error inflating class <unknown>
E/AndroidRuntime(18485):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
E/AndroidRuntime(18485):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
E/AndroidRuntime(18485):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
E/AndroidRuntime(18485):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
E/AndroidRuntime(18485):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
E/AndroidRuntime(18485):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
E/AndroidRuntime(18485):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
E/AndroidRuntime(18485):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
E/AndroidRuntime(18485):    at tw.com.a_i_t.IPCamViewer.FileBrowser.FileBrowserFragment.onCreateView(FileBrowserFragment.java:200)
E/AndroidRuntime(18485):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:833)
E/AndroidRuntime(18485):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1039)
E/AndroidRuntime(18485):    at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:635)
E/AndroidRuntime(18485):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1405)
E/AndroidRuntime(18485):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:441)
E/AndroidRuntime(18485):    at tw.com.a_i_t.IPCamViewer.MainActivity.addFragment(MainActivity.java:131)
E/AndroidRuntime(18485):    at tw.com.a_i_t.IPCamViewer.Viewer.MjpegPlayerFragment$4.onClick(MjpegPlayerFragment.java:1145)
E/AndroidRuntime(18485):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4147)
E/AndroidRuntime(18485):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17161)
E/AndroidRuntime(18485):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
E/AndroidRuntime(18485):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
E/AndroidRuntime(18485):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
E/AndroidRuntime(18485):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4786)
E/AndroidRuntime(18485):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(18485):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
E/AndroidRuntime(18485):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
E/AndroidRuntime(18485):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
E/AndroidRuntime(18485):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(18485): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
E/AndroidRuntime(18485):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(18485):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
E/AndroidRuntime(18485):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
E/AndroidRuntime(18485):    ... 26 more
E/AndroidRuntime(18485): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
E/AndroidRuntime(18485):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(18485):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:500)
E/AndroidRuntime(18485):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:353)
E/AndroidRuntime(18485):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:785)
E/AndroidRuntime(18485):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1935)
E/AndroidRuntime(18485):    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
E/AndroidRuntime(18485):    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3392)
E/AndroidRuntime(18485):    at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:114)
E/AndroidRuntime(18485):    at android.widget.ImageButton.<init>(ImageButton.java:87)
E/AndroidRuntime(18485):    at android.widget.ImageButton.<init>(ImageButton.java:83)
E/AndroidRuntime(18485):    ... 29 more
W/ActivityManager(  568):   Force finishing activity tw.com.a_i_t.IPCamViewer/.MainActivity
```

Can someone teach me how to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your crash has nothing to do with your relatively strange method of calling the Activity (what is that "addFragment method?!?)…

…anyway your crash is because you are running out of memory when inflating the ImageView:

```
E/dalvikvm-heap(18485): Out of memory on a 4194320-byte allocation.
```

Your `android:background="@drawable/phone_album"` is probably too big (or one of the other drawables).

Do yourself a favor and use [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso) to load images. There are so many things that you can do wrong when loading images that it's best to leave it to those who have experience with it ;)

Answer (score 1):

There is no ImageButton with id `R.id.FileButton` in your layout xml

Also

```
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
```

You need to scale down the image.

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

You can also check this

[Out of Memory error with Bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16765899/out-of-memory-error-with-bitmap)

Comment: Sorry , your answer is very good , too. But I have to choose one , so I choose the answer who early answer.

Comment: @MartinWun i believe i answered first and i also mentioned about id. any way choice to tick the answer is left to oyu

Answer (score 0):

In the XML layout you posted, I can't see the ImageView with the id `FileButton`. Where is it?
As to the `Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` line, have a look at similar questions:

[Strange out of memory issue while loading an image to a Bitmap object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/strange-out-of-memory-issue-while-loading-an-image-to-a-bitmap-object)

and

[Android : java.lang.OutOfMemoryError:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19558713/android-java-lang-outofmemoryerror)