# How to set layout params on an imageView inside GridView in Android

Tags: android, gridview, out-of-memory, kotlin

I am new to android and I met this tutorial at [the official android site](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html) on how to create a `GridView` of images. I am using kotlin as the language of choice. In the adapter class which extends `BaseAdapter`, I am trying to set the imageview layoutparams as indicated in the tutorial, but I get an error saying `GridView.LayoutParams` is unresolved reference. Here is the complete code for the class:

```
class ImageAdapter(val context: Context) : BaseAdapter() {
    // references to our images
    val items: IntArray = intArrayOf(R.drawable.cat, R.drawable.daft_punk, R.drawable.gun, R.drawable.harvestors, R.drawable.intel, R.drawable.maserati, R.drawable.porsche, R.drawable.serveroom, R.drawable.spiderman, R.drawable.watch_dog)
    override fun getItem(p0: Int): Any {
        TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }

    override fun getItemId(p0: Int): Long {
        return 0
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return items.size
    }

    // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    override fun getView(p0: Int, p1: View?, p2: ViewGroup?): View {
        var imageView: ImageView
        if (p1 == null) {
      // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            imageView= ImageView(context)
            imageView.layoutParams= GridView.LayoutParams(85,85)
            imageView.scaleType = ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP
            imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8)
        } else {
            imageView=p1 as ImageView
        }
        imageView.setImageResource(items[p0])
        return imageView
    }

}
```

The error is in the `getView` method at the line `imageView.layoutParams=GridView.LayoutParams(85,85)`. The `LayoutParams` is in red which means error, and when I hover on it, I get the message:

> Unresolved reference: LayoutParams

How do I successfully set these `LayoutParams`? Because without them images in the `GridView` are displaying in their full height and I need a small image the same way the gallery app displays them in our phones.

### Subsequent question:

When I replace the `imageView.layoutParams=GridView.LayoutParams(85,85)` with `imageView.layoutParams=AbsListView.LayoutParams(85,85)`, I get a javaOutOfMemory error.
The following is the full stack trace:

```
08-16 06:58:11.412 4543-4543/gallerie.classmite.com.imageviewer E/dalvikvm-heap: Out of memory on a 18662416-byte allocation.
08-16 06:58:11.431 4543-4543/gallerie.classmite.com.imageviewer E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Process: gallerie.classmite.com.imageviewer, PID: 4543                                                                                  java.lang.OutOfMemoryError                                                                                                                                          
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)                                                                                      
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:609                                                                                      
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)                                                                                     
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:840)                                                                                     
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2166)                                                                                     
at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:710)                                                                                      
at android.widget.ImageView.resolveUri(ImageView.java:638)                                                                                      
at android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(ImageView.java:367)                                                                                     
at gallerie.classmite.com.imageviewer.ImageAdapter.getView(ImageAdapter.kt:32)                                                                                       
at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2372)                                                                                      
at android.widget.GridView.makeAndAddView(GridView.java:1345)                                                                                      
at android.widget.GridView.makeRow(GridView.java:345)                                                                                     
at android.widget.GridView.fillDown(GridView.java:287)                                                                                      
at android.widget.GridView.fillFromTop(GridView.java:421)                                                                                      
at android.widget.GridView.layoutChildren(GridView.java:1233)                                                                                      
at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2166)                                                                                      
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15127)                                                                                      
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4862)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1888)                                                                                      
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1742)                                                                                     
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1651)                                                                                     
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15127)                                                                                      
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4862)                                                                                     
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:515)                                                                                      
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:450)                                                                                      
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15127)                                                                                      
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4862)                                                                                      
at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:374)                                                                                      
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15127)                                                                                      
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4862)                                                                                     
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:515)                                                                                      
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:450)                                                                                     
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15127)                                                                                     
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4862)                                                                                     
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2315)                                                                                     
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2021)                                                                                     
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1189)                                                                                     
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6221)                                                                                     
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:788)                                                                                      
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:591)                                                                                     
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:560)                                                                                     
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:774)                                                                                     
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)                                                                                      
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)                                                                                      
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)                                                                                      
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5315)                                                                                      
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)                                                                                     
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)                                                                                   
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:829)                                                                                    
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:645)                                                                                     
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The error only occurs when I run the app in my phone, but when I run the app in the emulator, it works flawlessly after I made the replacement above.

Comment: What is the sizes of images you are loading in imageView?

Comment: The largest is almost 2MB with a majority being less than 1MB...also when I load many smaller images say above 15 in total, i get the same error

Comment: Try using Glide lib https://github.com/bumptech/glide. It is really easy to implement along with Bitmap caching and pooling and can handle your use case easily.

Comment: Ok..will definately give a try..

Answer (score 4):

You can try with this:

```
imageView.layoutParams = AbsListView.LayoutParams(85, 85)
```

`AbsListView.LayoutParams` is used in `GridView` when retrieving childs' `LayoutParams`.

Since static member can be inherited by subclass [in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10291949/are-static-methods-inherited-in-java). When you call `GridView.LayoutParams`, it is actually `AbsListView.LayoutParams`. However, in Kotlin, you cannot do it the same way. Outside of the subclass, you can only reference the members of the companion object of the super class using the name of super class.

### Updates for Subsequent question:

The `OutOfMemory` error indicates that you are loading large image to `ImageView`. To prevent this, you have to scale down the image before displaying it, referring to this [tutorial](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap.html). You may also use some image loading framework, such as [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide), to display your image.

Suggested reading: [Strange out of memory issue while loading an image to a Bitmap object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/strange-out-of-memory-issue-while-loading-an-image-to-a-bitmap-object)

Comment: I am getting a `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` error on the closing curly brace of the else statement..

Comment: This should be another issue. Do you have a full stack trace about it? You may update the question about this new issue.

Comment: It your image resource is too large, you may refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20817369/outofmemory-error-using-imageview) or find some way to get a resized bitmap before passing it to `ImageView`.

Comment: I think the problem was the images. When I run the app in the emulator it works maybe because the computer has no restrictions on RAM unlike the phone...What I have done is use smaller images which occupy less memory and it has worked...I want to make my own version of the gallery app, and this means that the images (no matter how large they are), are hosted in the phones file manager and not drawable folder. Do you think am likely to face the memory issue if i fetch the images from the phone?

Comment: It can be easy to encounter memory issue when you are dealing with image in Android. To prevent this, you have to [scale down](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap.html) the image before displaying it. You may also see some suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/strange-out-of-memory-issue-while-loading-an-image-to-a-bitmap-object).

Comment: You may take a look at [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) also.

Comment: @BakaWaii consider editing your question, as it is not helpful for this question. mention about memory issue there also. Any visitor is less likely to check comments.

Comment: @chandil03 Thanks for the suggestion. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Don't set the layout params as u did

the correct way is 
imageParams=(GridView.LayoutParams) imageView.getLayoutParams();

in above line "GridView" should be replaced with parent View of your imageView

Happy coding.. :)