# GridView.LayoutParams doesn't exist in Kotlin?

Tags: java, android, gridview, kotlin

I want to use `GridView` and according to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html), in adapter I can use this line in adapter:

```
 imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
```

Well, converting it to Kotlin, it says:

[image]

It works in Java, but not in Kotlin.

So, why is that? And how can I use `GridView.LayoutParams` in Kotlin?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45703751/how-to-set-layout-params-on-an-imageview-inside-gridview-in-android

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try one of the following:

```
imageView.setLayoutParams(AbsListView.LayoutParams(85, 85))
imageView.setLayoutParams(GridView@AbsListView.LayoutParams(85, 85))
```

Since GridView doesn't have it's own implementation of LayoutParams you have to choose an implementation of its superclass `AbsListView`. You can decide if you want to add the `GridView@` prefix.

Answer (score 4):

`GridView` doesnt have inner class `LayoutParams`, it uses `AbsListView.LayoutParams`

so just change code to

```
imageView.layoutParams = AbsListView.LayoutParams(85,85)
```