# Android Studio: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, android, android-layout, out-of-memory, android-studio-2.0

I am trying to get my application to display different views when Image buttons are clicked. Its a fairly simple application, but I cant test to see if it works because I keep getting an Out of Memory Error. Here is the java class

Edit:

I decreased the size of the button images by 50% and I still get an out of memory error. Additionally I added android:largeHeap="true" to the android manifest. Below are the original files but with updates

**Dashboard.java**

```
    package com.pixel.deloitte.xprizeapplication;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Dashboard extends AppCompatActivity {
    //private TabHost tabHost;
    //private int[] tabs = {R.drawable.dashboardnotclicked,R.drawable.teamreviewnotclicked,R.drawable.teambiosnotclicked,R.drawable.mentornotclicked,R.drawable.schedulenotclicked};
    public static class MyUncaughtExceptionHandler implements Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler {
        @Override
        public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable ex) {
            if (ex.getClass().equals(OutOfMemoryError.class)) {
                try {
                    android.os.Debug.dumpHprofData("/sdcard/dump.hprof");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //Thread.currentThread().setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new MyUncaughtExceptionHandler());
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard);
        findViewById(R.id.login).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    public void buttonClick(View v){
        switch(v.getId()){
            case R.id.loginButton:
                break;
            case R.id.dashboardbtn:
                break;
            case R.id.teamreviewbtn:
                break;
            case R.id.teambios:
                break;
            case R.id.mentorsbtn:
                break;
            case R.id.schedulebtn:
                break;
        }
    }

}
```

Here is the error I get, the error is thrown at setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard)

**java.lang.OutOfMemoryError**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                 Process: com.pixel.deloitte.xprizeapplication, PID: 2573
                                                 java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
                                                     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
                                                     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:587)
                                                     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:422)
                                                     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:840)
                                                     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2115)
                                                     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
                                                     at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:129)
                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:57)
                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:53)
                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:106)
                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:1008)
                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:1067)
                                                     at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:756)
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:759)
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:759)
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:759)
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:759)
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280)
                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
                                                     at com.pixel.deloitte.xprizeapplication.Dashboard.onCreate(Dashboard.java:36)
                                                     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
                                                     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is
**activity_dashboard.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="900dp"
    tools:context=".Dashboard"
    android:background="@color/AppBackground">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="850dp"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/login">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="761dp"
                android:layout_height="876dp"
                android:id="@+id/visioneervideo"
                android:src="@drawable/video" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/signin">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="295dp"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="203dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

                    <EditText
                        android:layout_width="295dp"
                        android:layout_height="49dp"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:id="@+id/editText"
                        android:background="@drawable/username"
                        android:editable="true"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:text="Username"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

                    <EditText
                        android:layout_width="295dp"
                        android:layout_height="49dp"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:id="@+id/editText2"
                        android:background="@drawable/username"
                        android:editable="true"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:text="Password"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
                        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText"
                        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:id="@+id/loginButton"
                        android:src="@drawable/login"
                        android:onClick="buttonClick" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="850dp"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
        android:background="@color/AppBackground">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/appactivities">

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="64dp"
                android:id="@+id/optionsmenu"
                android:background="@color/DashboardBackgroundnew">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="241dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/xprizelogo"
                    android:background="@drawable/xprizelogo" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="141dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/dashboardbtn"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_dashboard" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="148dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/teamreviewbtn"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_teamreview" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="126dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/teambiosbtn"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_teambios" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="119.5dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/mentorsbtn"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_mentor" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="127.5dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/schedulebtn"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_schedule" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="64dp"
                    android:layout_height="64dp"
                    android:id="@+id/twitterbtn"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_twitter" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/profilebtn" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <ViewStub android:id="@+id/stub"
                android:inflatedId="@+id/subTree"
                android:layout_width="120dip"
                android:layout_height="40dip" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and here is the manifest

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.pixel.deloitte.xprizeapplication">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="XPrize"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".Dashboard">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25719620/how-to-solve-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-trouble-in-android

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19558713/android-java-lang-outofmemoryerror

Comment: There's two solutions known to me where one is to perform the operation in thread and split the operation and another is to increase the heapsize of the app where the second option is not recommended

Answer (score 10):

Set largeHeap property as True in `AndroidManifest.xml` by,

```
android:largeHeap="true"
```

So you can modify the `AndroidManifest.xml` as,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.pixel.deloitte.xprizeapplication">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="XPrize"
        android:supportsRtl="true"

        android:largeHeap="true"

        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".Dashboard">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your images on the buttons are (way) to big, so that to display them more Memory is needed than available, simply create icons / smaller versions of the images and have those shown on the buttons

Comment: I cut the size of each image by 50% and I still get a out of memory error

Comment: Well how big are they now still? @DerekDeLizo