# how to correct this error: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

Tags: android, memory, out-of-memory

This is my code:

```
public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
    Bitmap foto = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
    wid = foto.getWidth();
    hgt = foto.getHeight();

    Bitmap newImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(wid, hgt, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(newImage);
    canvas.drawBitmap(foto, 0f, 0f, null);
    if (newImage.getWidth() > newImage.getHeight()) {
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postRotate(90);
        newImage.createBitmap(newImage, 0, 0, wid, hgt, matrix, true);

    }
}
```

This is my error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:689)
at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:666)
at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:633)
at com.supratecnologia.activity.Camera_Activity.onPictureTaken(Camera_Activity.java:189)
at android.hardware.Camera$EventHandler.handleMessage(Camera.java:768)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: The error is pretty clear, you're using too much memory I recommend you to check the memory usage of your application and track exactly when this error happens.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17990086/out-of-memory-while-creating-bitmaps-on-device/17990482#17990482

Answer (score 10, accepted):

ost of times this happens due to large bitmap cross the limit of VM heap, so you need to scale down your image or to lower the quality of you image.

To scale image use `BitmapFactory.Options`.

```
Bitmap bm = null;
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inSampleSize = 5;
AssetFileDescriptor fileDescriptor =null;
try {
    fileDescriptor = this.getContentResolver().openAssetFileDescriptor(selectedImage,”r”);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
finally{
    try {
        bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor(), null, options);
        fileDescriptor.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Or use `Bitmap.compress()` to lower quality of image.

And you can also follow this [conversation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/strange-out-of-memory-issue-while-loading-an-image-to-a-bitmap-object) to avoid memory error while loading images in Bitmap.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an emulator you might have a value for VM Heap too low for that emulator instance. Check the Advanced Option in the emulator and try increasing the value for VM Heap. It happened to me that in my phone was working but not in the emulator for the low VM Heap value.
Anyway, if you don't have lots of images probably they have a resolution too high.