# Taking a picture and using the image - Out of memory error

Tags: java, android, image, bitmap, camera

OK, I am developing an android application that takes a photo using the camera, then uses that image in an ImageView.
The problem that I'm having is that I keep getting an `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` exception when I try and load the image.

Code to start camera intent:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(AddVehicleActivity.this);
        builder.setTitle("Select A Method");
        builder.setItems(R.array.array_PhotoMethods, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                switch(which) {
                case 0 :
                    IMAGE_LOCATION = Utility.setFileName(_session); //Returns image path
                    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(new File(IMAGE_LOCATION)));
                    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);
                    break;
                }
            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }
});
```

From my understanding, this will allow the image to be saved at the full resolution of the camera which I can confirm through the image details in the gallery.  Using my Samsung SIII, my image is about 3.3MB. So, I am able to use the camera and store the image I take using the camera to path I specify.  The problem comes when trying to use the image.

To load the image, I use the following:

```
public static Bitmap Shrink(String file, int width, int height) {
    BitmapFactory.Options bmpFactoryOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    int heightRatio = (int)Math.ceil(bmpFactoryOptions.outHeight/(float)height);
    int widthRatio = (int)Math.ceil(bmpFactoryOptions.outWidth/(float)width);
    if (heightRatio > 1 || widthRatio > 1) {
        bmpFactoryOptions.inSampleSize = (heightRatio > widthRatio) ? heightRatio : widthRatio;
    }
    return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file, bmpFactoryOptions);
}
```

I have rewritten this functions a few different ways and found out that sometimes, I get the memory error when calling `BitmapFactory.decodeFile`

My stack trace looks like this:

```
E/dalvikvm-heap(8355): Out of memory on a 31961104-byte allocation.
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:619)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:385)
    at com.autopilot.com.objects.Images.Shrink(Images.java:191)
    at com.autopilot.com.adapters.ImageAdapter.getView(ImageAdapter.java:90)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2437)
    at android.widget.GridView.onMeasure(GridView.java:1030)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15395)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4826)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1396)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1038)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:576)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15395)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4826)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1396)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1038)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:576)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15395)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4826)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.forceUniformWidth(LinearLayout.java:926)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:906)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15395)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:617)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:399)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15395)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4826)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15395)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:833)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15395)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4826)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2362)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15395)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1985)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1226)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1399)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1119)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4553)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4950)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1004)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

From tracing this through, the memory exception occurs anytime that the original bitmap is loaded.  I cannot find a way to set the saved image size and when I try to save the bitmap from the intent extras, it's never big enough, usually thumb nail size.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: do you have tried to load the image by BufferedInputStream?

Comment: refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18376147/out-of-memory-exception-while-scroll-listview/18376341#18376341

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Comment: I just attempted it and received the same error

Comment: What values do you use for `width` and `height` passed to the `Shrink` method?

Answer (score 1):

OK, I found the answer, thank you sunil!

```
public static Bitmap Shrink(String file, int width, int height) {
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file, options);
    options.inSampleSize = calcSize(options, width, height);
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file, options);
    return bmp;
}

public static int calcSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, int width, int height) {
    final int uHeight = options.outHeight;
    final int uWidth = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;
    if (uHeight > height || uWidth > width) {
        if (uWidth > uHeight) {
            inSampleSize = Math.round((float) uHeight / (float) height);
        } else {
            inSampleSize = Math.round((float) uWidth / (float) width);
        }
    }
    return inSampleSize;
}
```

Comment: What is this code doing? How it solves the problem?