# android listview outofmemory - ImageBitmaps

Tags: android, listview, gridview

I have a `ListView` and a `GridView` both causing me problems and `OutOfMemory` errors when scrolling, I read online about the issue and saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18376147/out-of-memory-exception-while-scroll-listview) question so I used Sunil's first solution and implemented it in my code. the images for the `GridView` and `ListView` are at "/res/drawable/image1.png" and so on, I passed to the `CustomAdapter` class this int array `public static int[] mDrawableImg = {R.drawable.back, R.drawable.arrows, R.drawable.bomber, R.drawable.archers, R.drawable.knight};` and used this:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    final Holder holder = new Holder();
    final View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.program_list2, null);
    holder.img = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
      holder.img.setImageResource(imageId[position]);
  //  holder.img.setImageBitmap(convertBitmap(String.valueOf(imageId[position])));
            return rowView;
}
```

Now as you see I added a line of code to load the image from `Bitmap` with a function called `convertBitmap` but my `GridView` is empty, its scrollable meaning there are items but the images are not loaded.

`convertBitmap` **Function:**

```
public static Bitmap convertBitmap(String path) {
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    BitmapFactory.Options bfOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bfOptions.inDither = false;
    bfOptions.inTempStorage = new byte[32 * 1024];
    File file = new File(path);
    FileInputStream fs = null;
    try {
        fs = new FileInputStream(file);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        if (fs != null) {
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fs.getFD(), null, bfOptions);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (fs != null) {
            try {
                fs.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return bitmap;
}
```

What have I done wrong and will it solve my `OutOfMemory` errors? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you get is absolutely logical. Look at this line in your `getView()` method:

`final View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.program_list2, null);`

What does it mean? It means that you're creating a new instance of the item each time Android requests you a `View` for it. That's pretty insane, because you just create and create more views while you scroll the `ListView` (so is pretty natural that you get an out of memory error. And I'm sure your `ListView` is scrolling laggy).

And I bet Android Studio is warning you this issue by remarking that line in yellow color.

Affortunately, you can fix it very easily. But let me say you some things. Look at the `View` that you're receiving in the `getView()` method as a parameter. Don't you see it? Is the variable that you called `convertView`. And note that you're not using it. What is this `View`? Is called a recycled view (Not to be confused with `RecyclerView` class). Is a view that was previously inflated and no longer used because is not visible for the user. And this, my friend, this is the key of your problem and also of your solution: Instead of inflate one new view each time, just recycle it. I promise you is very simple. Now your `getView` methos should look like this:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null)
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.program_list2, null);

    //final Holder holder = new Holder();
    //holder.img = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    //holder.img.setImageResource(imageId[position]);


    ImageView img = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    //Note you don't need the Holder
    Bitmap imageBitmap = convertBitmap(imageId[position]);
    if (imageBitmap != null)
        img.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
    else
        img.setImageBitmap(null);

    return convertView;
}
```

And please look at your usage of the ViewHolder pattern. You're using it wrong...

Comment: You are returning the rowView but it doesn't exist, what should I do with it?

Comment: @DAVIDBALAS1Oh, my mistake. Look at the edited answer. You should use the same convertView

Comment: @DAVIDBALAS1 Yes, you're doing Bitmap inflation in the main thread. And you're not caching Bitmaps. You should lay off those tasks to other threads... Or at least cache them using LruCache. Google for it... And, also, review your ViewHolder... Is misused here. It has no impact on the performance... You create a Holder, you assign it an image and then you're done with it and you return a View? The Holder is created and never used. (I wouldn't like to think that you're using it as a variable class...). Look at my new edit...

Comment: Thanks, it's a bit complicated but anyway, even if I am doing the Bitmap inflation in the main thread, it still should work but ineffectively isn't it? it doesn't show me nothing

Comment: @DAVIDBALAS1 Yes, but first be sure that `imageId[position]` is not returning you null... Look at my new edit and let me know if that actually works...

Comment: What are you storing on the imageId array?

Comment: I used your code and it's now successfully load all the grid with imagebitmaps but strangely, it shows on every item the first image in imageId array..

Comment: nope, now it's empty, if it matters you can't use:         Bitmap imageBitmap = convertBitmap(imageId[position]); as it requires a String so maybe         Bitmap imageBitmap = convertBitmap(String.valueOf(imageId[position]));
but still nope..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115023/discussion-between-joaquin-and-davidbalas1).