# Clearing heap memory for Out of Memory Exception

Tags: android, memory, garbage-collection

I Know the question regarding out of memory already been asked ,but i found no solution

In Bitmap Factory i got out of memory Exception, even use

```
inSampleSize=1
```

so i use to surrounded it by try catch out of memory exception since it is a bad practice

```
try{
   .........
   ......
}catch (OutOfMemoryError e)
            {}
```

out of memory exception also caught 
 but my question is after caught of this exception shall we

> Clearing or reallocating heap memory of GC

is there any solution ?

i use

> System.gc();

no use
please help!!!!!!!

> ```
> not even Bitmap also for GridView Orientation 
> i found this exception
> Clamp target GC heap from 17.333MB to 16.000MB
> Out of memory on a 140416-byte allocation.
> ```

Comment: Just search for "android out of memory", you will find many questions with every possible solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Strange out of memory issue while loading an image to a Bitmap object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/strange-out-of-memory-issue-while-loading-an-image-to-a-bitmap-object)

Comment: @Simon  ya i seen that , i also use to do that code but the image which is use to display will be blurred not good to see

Comment: see accepted ans- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17990086/out-of-memory-while-creating-bitmaps-on-device/17990482#17990482

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After 3 days of struggle i found a solution for not increasing Heap memory by using
this

i replace all my ImageView like this

```
<com.example.util.SingleShotImageView
                    android:id="@+id/grid_image"
                    android:layout_width="170dp"
                    android:layout_height="240dp"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                     />
```

Using this class  i use to clear the Image bitmap heap size in onDetachedFromWindow function

```
public class SingleShotImageView extends ImageView {

    public SingleShotImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public SingleShotImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public SingleShotImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDetachedFromWindow () {
        setImageDrawable(null);
        setBackgroundDrawable(null);
        setImageBitmap(null);
        System.gc();
    }

}
```

now it works fine and my heap memory remains

> Grow heap (frag case) to 11.719MB for 8192016-byte allocation

Comment: Hi, I change my code to exactly what you said but the problem is onDetachedFromWindow() method never calls in activities while calls when I'm replacing fragments! So, my app still crashing on activities.

Comment: Oh GOD , I need It , Some Nights Didn't Slept To Find Solution , onDetachedFromWindow  method Clean Custom ImageView